# Data conversion on which side is prefer backend or frontend

Tags: algorithm

I am trying to do the data conversion of application data, which side we have to do the the conversion backend or frontend side. Unit will be depend on the user selection which will store in the database.

Comment: Data conversion is usually done on the backend to 1. ensure its validity and 2. take the computation load off the user. However, there isn't really enough information in this question to give more advice for a specific use case.

Answer (score 0):

Tldr: backend

Long post:

That's a subjective question so I will ask it in a subjective way:

The frontend is usually used for UI or operations that involve more or less directly the user.

So any kind of background processing that does NOT involve the user should be done in backend. Also it is done in such manner in order to reduce the load time and to take the computation load off the user

See also :

[front_end_wiki](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front-end_web_development)
[Frontend_vs_backend](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_and_back_ends)